# BIRT report modification

Tags: eclipse, birt, erp, ofbiz

I am a student who is new with OFBIZ and BIRT , I am trying to modify the existing report "**Payments Report**" , but i cant get any data . and i think because of that i am getting error ,

```
The following items have errors:

ReportDesign (id = 1):
+ An exception occurred during processing. Please see the following message for     details:
A BIRT exception occurred. See next exception for more information.
Invalid javascript expression: measure["amount"] (Element ID:1)
+ Can not find the prepared query org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.olap.impl.query.CubeQueryDefinition@a91e3d. (Element ID:1)
```

this is the script in ofbiz "open":

```
payments = null;
userLogin = null;
parameters = null;
try {
    userLogin = delegator.findByPrimaryKey("UserLogin",UtilMisc.toMap("userLoginId","admin"));
} catch(e) {
        Debug.logError(e,"");
}
input =  FastMap.newInstance();
inputFields =  FastMap.newInstance();
if(params!=null){
    inputFields.put("partyIdTo", params["partyIdTo"]);
    inputFields.put("paymentId", params["paymentId"]);
    inputFields.put("paymentTypeId", params["paymentTypeId"]);
    inputFields.put("paymentId_op", params["paymentId_op"]);
    inputFields.put("paymentRefNum_ic", params["paymentRefNum_ic"]);
    inputFields.put("noConditionFind", params["noConditionFind"]);
    inputFields.put("partyIdFrom", params["partyIdFrom"]);
    inputFields.put("paymentRefNum_op", params["paymentRefNum_op"]);
    inputFields.put("amount", params["amount"]);
    inputFields.put("statusId", params["statusId"]);
    inputFields.put("paymentGatewayResponseId", params["paymentGatewayResponseId"]);
    inputFields.put("paymentId_ic", params["paymentId_ic"]);
    inputFields.put("paymentRefNum", params["paymentRefNum"]);
    inputFields.put("comments_ic", params["comments_ic"]);
    inputFields.put("comments_op", params["comments_op"]);
    inputFields.put("comments", params["comments"]);
}
input.put("userLogin",userLogin);
input.put("inputFields",inputFields);
input.put("entityName","PaymentAndType");
input.put("orderBy","effectiveDate DESC");
//input.put("viewIndex", 0);
//input.put("viewSize", 20);
try {
    result = dispatcher.runSync("performFind", input);
    payments = result.get("listIt");
} catch (e) {
    Debug.logError(e, module);
}
```

i have modified the Entityengine.xml and got derby OFBIZ schema to the Oracle.
and I try to change the script file with modifications , but after few modifications (ofbiz Data source is uneditable,i have use eclipse to edit **.rptdesign** file) i got this error .

(the "Payments Report" is build in : "Eclipse BIRT Designer Version 2.5.1.v20090903"
but i use : "Eclipse BIRT Designer Version 4.3.1.v201309091055" so When save and run this , i get error )

```
org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: The design file <stream> has error and can not be run.
```

as i found, this happens when version incompatibility , So how can i change this file and get data ? . what i am doing wrong ?  thanks and sorry for bad English and any lack of information.

Answer (score 0):

In BIRT Designer, try making a simple change to the rptdesign file (such as updating the description) and then save it (and not run at the same time). This should update the file to the latest version of BIRT Designer. Then try running it again to see if the EngineException goes away.

Comment: Hi @user3660637 - yap i tryed slowly modifying it with both versions upto few modifications it was ok . but after few a config file will be there and i am getting the error `org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: The design file <stream> has error and can not be run.` . so any tips ? and sorry for late replay.

Answer (score 0):

BIRT is backwards compatible, so early versions reports (2.5) will run on new versions (4.3) of BIRT. I see that you say you have already tried to save the report but the report is still listing as version 2.5 which means it is not saving your changes. If the report was being updated it would update to the new version (4.3) you are building with.

Most likely there is an error in the existing report that was ignored by 2.5 but will not run in 4.3.

The easiest solution (and best for your education) is to rebuild the report in 4.3 from scratch.  Test it as you build to make sure it runs in it's simplest form.  As you build you will either find and correct the design flaw that is allowed in 2.5 OR as you are building with 4.3 you will not create the flaw/error at all.

Comment: Hi , james- really thanks for the input.I have try with both version so far . if i rebuild it with 4.3 i get `org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: The design file <stream> has error and can not be run.`

Comment: Hi , @James - really thanks for the input.I have try with both version so far . if i rebuild it with 4.3 i get `org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: The design file <stream> has error and can not be run.` and if i build it with 2.5 i get classdif error with drivers(birt EngineException) .

Comment: @Archangle From your comment in the answer it sounds like you are building in the error.  Not sure anyone here will be able to help you with your problem.

Comment: @ James , yap maybe :( , but even before i change it  , it was not working , I have download the new OFBiz(rel on 8/10/2014) seems like they have remove that report (and seems like all BIRT technology , not 100% sure need to go through documents) . any way currently i am tiring to go over the 2.5 and make fix the existing script (not jdbc drive)

Comment: @ James , I know its unrelevant in this question . but do you know whats with new update and Birt , have they move it as a new component? or are they remove it 100% ? any place i can find official note on that ?